# Unable to return selected data angularjs

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, factory

I created a service named  `ProductStorage` to retrieve data from sqlite database using angularjs.It selecting data properly and get result in console when i call it like `ProductStorage.product(1)`, but it return `{}` always.

```
.factory('ProductStorage', function() {
return {
   product:function(product_id){
      var product  = {};
      db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = "+product_id,[],function(tx, res){
              product = angular.fromJson(res.rows.item(0).productdata);   
              console.log(product);  // shows result in console   
            });
         });
      return product; // not returning product ,always return {}
   }
}
})
```

Comment: what's `db` ? Have you tried using the $q deferred object + getting the returned promise ?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is you are reassigning `product` and that breaks the *reference* to the original object.

The sqlite transaction is *asynchronous*.

Thus the object that is returned from service is not the same object you log inside the `executeSql` callback.

One fix would be to `extend` the original object instead of reassigning the variable:

```js
tx.executeSql("...", [], function (tx, res) {
    var data = angular.fromJson(res.rows.item(0).productdata);
    // don't break original reference, just update the object properties
    angular.extend(product, data);         
});
```

The alternative would be to use `$q` to create a promise that gets returned from service and you resolve that promise in the `executeSql` callback